# Can we say that all singletons are closed by this way?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

We know that a closed ball in space $E$:

$\bar{B}_{\epsilon}(x)=$ {$ y\in E: d(x,y) \leq \epsilon$} is a closed set.

If we consider, for example, $\epsilon = 0$,  $\bar{B}_{0}(x)= $ {$x$} , so every singleton {$x$} can be represented by a closed ball of radius zero and center $x$, which's a closed set. However, I know that singletons are open in some sets like  $\mathbb{N}$, so are singletons closed in all sets but open is some of them? Or the reason I put is incorrect?

Thanks!

Comment: "Open" does *not* mean "not closed"...

Comment: "A subset is not like a door: it can be open, closed, both, or neither." - from Wiki article on [door spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Door_space).

Answer (score 3):

By definition, the radius of a ball (open or closed) is greater than $0$. However, it is easy to prove that, in a metric space, all singletons are closed: if $x\in E$,$$E\setminus\{x\}=\bigcup_{y\in E\setminus\{x\}}B_{d(y,x)}(y),$$and this proves that $E\setminus\{x\}$ is an open set.

Yes, in some cases, some singletons are open . So what?

Comment: are the Balls of y closed or open here?

Comment: @JosephRock As I wrote in my answer, what I wrote works both for open and for closed balls.

Comment: yes but in the first case they must be open right?

Comment: @JosephRock What is “the first case”?

Comment: As you said E\ {x} = U Bd(y,x) (y) .. this i refer to as the first case, the balls have to be open in this case, therefore the singletons are closed in a metric space? @jose Carlos Santos

Comment: @JosephRock Yes. The notation $B_r(x)$ is used for the *open* ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113975/discussion-between-joseph-rock-and-jose-carlos-santos).

Answer (score 1):

To prove that any singleton $\{x\}$ is closed in space $X$, we can prove that $X\setminus\{x\}$ is open. For that to be true, it is enough to prove that for all $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$ there exists open $U_y\ni y$ such that $U_y\subseteq X\setminus\{x\}$; in that case we could write $$X\setminus\{x\} = \bigcup_{y\in X\setminus\{x\}} U_y.$$

On the other hand, condition $y\in U_y$ and $U_y\subseteq X\setminus\{x\}$ is equivalent to $y\in U_y,\ x\not\in U_y$. Thus, singleton $\{x\}$ is closed if and only if $$(\forall y\neq x)(\exists\ \text{open}\ U)\ y\in U,\ x\not\in U.$$

This is closely related to the notion of [$T_1$-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space), where every two distinct points $x,y$ have open neighbourhoods not containing the other point. Equivalent way to say this is to say that all singletons are closed.

A stronger condition than $T_1$ is [$T_2$-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space) (more commonly referred to  as Hausdorff space) which says that every two distinct points $x,y$ have disjoint open neighbourhoods. It is obvious that $T_2$ implies $T_1$.

Finally, every metric space is a Hausdorff space. Let $x,y\in (X,d)$. Define $U = B(x,d(x,y)/2)$ and $V = B(y,d(x,y)/2)$. Then $U\cap V=\emptyset$ by triangle inequality which completes the proof. Thus, every metric space is Hausdorff and every singleton in a metric space is closed.

Considering $\mathbb N\subseteq \mathbb R$ with subspace topology, it is again a metric space with metric inherited from $\mathbb R$. Thus, all singletons are closed. However, all singletons are open as well, since an open ball with radius $1$ in $\mathbb N$ is given by $B(x,1) = \{y\in\mathbb N\mid d(x,y)<1\} = \{x\}$. This is an example of [discrete space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space).

Comment: well, the relevant relation is $[0,1)=[0,1]\cap(-1,1)$
an $[0,1]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, so $[0,1)$ is closed in $(-1,1)$ by prop. 1.3.4

Comment:  isn't closed in ℝ, but it is closed in  =[0,1)=[0,1]∩(−1,1)=[0,1]∩ =[0,1], =[0,1) using defn of relative topology , hey guys does anyone know if k here is closed in (-1,1)?

Comment: @Joseph Rock, how is that related to the question or my answer?